# Timber y WPML no traduce cadenas de texto

Tags: wordpress

Empece a utilizar [Timber](https://github.com/timber/timber) con Wordpress y todo estaba bien hasta que me toco hacer traducciones de textos. Utilizo WPML pero aparentemente no funciona con Timber.

Para traducir un texto con WPML normalmente utilizo lo siguiente:

```
_e('Texto', 'theme');
```

Ahora con Timber he probado esto:

```
{{ _e('Read more', 'theme') }}
{{ _e('string', 'theme') }}

{{ function("icl_translate", 'theme', 'string_identifier', 'string) }}

{{ dump(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE) }} // NULL
```

Pero parece que nada de esto funciona. Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Timber separa la lógica de la plantilla, esto hace que no puedas utilizar funciones PHP, como `_e()` o `__()`. Para traducir el tema, sería necesario crear una función o filtro twig para hacer, puedes probar con lo siguiente:

```
add_filter('get_twig', 'add_to_twig');

function add_to_twig($twig) {

$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader());

$twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('translate', 'create_translated_string'));
   return $twig;
}

function create_translated_string($text) {
    return __($text, 'theme_name');
}
```

Después solo tendrías que hacer pasar tus cadenas de texto por tu función twig.

```
{{ "Nombre" | translate }}
```

Con esto debería ser suficiente, pero puedes consultar más acerca de esto en la propia documentación de timber:
https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/Extending-Timber